# How do i map a linux network drive to linux mint?

Tags: linux, network-shares, linux-mint

Sorry, I'm new to linux and I've been searching on how to do this but all of the tutorials I've found are for mounting windows shares. I have a number of osx shares that I want to map to linux mint so that I can access it from the terminal window. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To have it mount automatically every time you boot, edit fstab:

**gksu pluma /etc/fstab**

then add an entry like this:

**192.168.1.199:/share/name /media/sharename nfs users,rw,auto 0 0**

Save, close, and then reboot, or to load the new fstab entry without rebooting:

**sudo mount -a**

Answer (score 0):

Run the mount command as root.

```
mount 10.3.0.12:/share/name /mnt/sharename -t nfs
```

You will probably need to install a couple of packages and start a couple of services for that to work properly. On my system, I can call /etc/rc.d/nfs start to get everything running, but more generally you will need to run: `rpcbind`, `rpc.pipefs` and `rpc.idmapd`. As for packages, I have something called net-fs/nfs-utils YMMV. Consult your distribution's documentation on the topic of "mounting NFS shares" for a more thorough explanation.